# Fetch records from table in the sequence of provided list in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, list

How can I fetch records from table in the same sequence of list of integer?

I have a `list<int>`

```
List<int> reorderNarrowerTermIds = new List<int>();
reorderNarrowerTermIds.Add(2,7,4,9);
```

Now I want to fetch records from table in the same order of above list.

```
var lstTerm = _context.table.Where(n => reorderNarrowerTermIds.Contains(n.TermId)).ToList();
```

Above linq statement gives records in 2,4,7,9 TermId sequence but I want in 2,7,4,9 TermId sequence.

I got stuck right here.

Comment: Maby try `.OrderBy(some property)`

Comment: @MKasprzyk .OrderBy will put it in a ascending or descending order, OP wants it in the same order as `reorderNarrowerTermIds`.

Comment: .OrderBy and .Select(n => n) not working at all.

Comment: Well i dont really understand what _context.table is and what information it might contain... if there are no dubplicates then swap arround _context.table. and ReordernarrowrTermIds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick , ordering by the index of occurrence:

```
var lstTerm = _context.table.Where(n => reorderNarrowerTermIds.Contains(n.TermId)).ToList()
                      .OrderBy(x => reorderNarrowerTermIds.IndexOf(x.TermId)).ToList();
```

So items at index 0 in `reorderNarrowerTermIds` have an order factor of `0` and shows up first in the resulting list. Same applies ascending for 1, 2, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Still unsure of what your information looks like that you are getting from `_context.table`

```
List<int> SearchNumbers = new List<int> { 2,7,4,8 };
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
var lstTerm = numbers.Where(n => SearchNumbers.Contains(n)).ToList();
```

This will display 2,4,7,8

```
List<int> SearchNumbers = new List<int> { 2,7,4,8 };
List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
var lstTerm = SearchNumbers.Where(n => numbers.Contains(n)).ToList();
```

This will display 2,7,4,8